# Iterating through an Xml can't see the second Child node (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, datatable

I'm iterating parallel in 2 Xml docs. When an element value X from first Xml is 
equal to the value in the second Xml (ex. USD== USD), it should write a 
row in a DataTable with two columns. Element value X (USD) in the first Column
and an other child element value Y (value from ) from first Xml in the second col.
The second Xml has a single node with multiple elements.

```
DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
dTable.Columns.Add("ColumnOne");
dTable.Columns.Add("ColumnTwo");
DataRow dRow = null;

foreach (XmlNode nodeFirst in firstXmlDoc.SelectNodes("//ValCurs/Valute")) 
{
    foreach (XmlNode nodeSecond in secondXmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("SelectedVal"))
    {
        if (nodeFirst.SelectSingleNode("CharCode").InnerText == nodeSecond.InnerText)
        {
            dRow = dTable.NewRow();
            dRow["ColumnOne"] = nodeFirst.SelectSingleNode("CharCode").InnerText;
            dRow["ColumnTwo"] = nodeFirst.SelectSingleNode("Value").InnerText;
            dTable.Rows.Add(dRow);
        }
    }
}
myDataGridView.DataSource = dTable;
```

This isn't working, I get in *"nodeFirst.SelectSingleNode("Value").InnerText"* a null value (" ") and it stops, filling the DataTable just with the *"CharCode"* value.
It's interesting that it worked the first few times I runned it, but it doesn't anymore.

First Xml:

```
<ValCurs>
    <Valute ID="47">
        <NumCode>978</NumCode>
        <CharCode>EUR</CharCode>
        <Nominal>1</Nominal>
        <Name>Euro</Name>
        <Value>20.3457</Value>
    </Valute>
    <Valute ID="44">
        <NumCode>840</NumCode>
        <CharCode>USD</CharCode>
        <Nominal>1</Nominal>
        <Name>Dolar S.U.A.</Name>
        <Value>17.4603</Value>
    </Valute>
    ...
</ValCurs>
```

Second Xml:

```
<SelectedVal>
    <Cod>UAH</Cod>
    <Cod>EUR</Cod>
    <Cod>CAD</Cod>
    <Cod>RON</Cod>
    <Cod>NOK</Cod>
    <Cod>RUB</Cod>
    <Cod>JPY</Cod>
    <Cod>AUD</Cod>
</SelectedVal>
```

Comment: you will need to share the xmls

Answer (score 0):

Try following code using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string CURRENCY_FILE = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string COUNTRY_FILE = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("NUMCODE", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("CHARCODE", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Nominal", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(decimal));


            XDocument currencyXml = XDocument.Load(CURRENCY_FILE);

            List<XElement> valutes = currencyXml.Descendants("Valute").ToList();

            foreach (XElement valute in valutes)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    (int)valute.Attribute("ID"),
                    (int)valute.Element("NumCode"),
                    (string)valute.Element("CharCode"),
                    (int)valute.Element("Nominal"),
                    (string)valute.Element("Name"),
                    (decimal)valute.Element("Value")
                });
            }

            XDocument countryXml = XDocument.Load(COUNTRY_FILE);

            List<string> countries = countryXml.Descendants("Cod").Select(x => (string)x).ToList();

            DataTable filteredTable = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => countries.Contains(x.Field<string>("CharCode"))).CopyToDataTable();
        }
    }
}
```